# Trim recorded audio and export

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am recording audio client-side, which is intended to be downloaded by the client. The audio needs to be synced up with some other things, but there is a significant delay (as much as 1s) between when other things start recording and when the MediaRecorder actually starts recording. I am trying to correct the length of the final recording by padding the beginning with silence and then chopping off the end; however, I'm not sure how to get a downloadable `Blob` from the resulting `AudioBuffer`.

Here is my code:

```js
let startTime, endTime, desiredLength;
let recorder;

const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$("#start").addEventListener("click", e => {
  startTime = performance.now();
  beginRecording(startTime);
});

$("#stop").addEventListener("click", e => {
  endTime = performance.now();
  desiredLength = endTime - startTime;
  recorder.stop();
});

async function beginRecording(startTime) {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  });

  const chunks = [];
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: "audio/webm"});

  let startDelay;

  // subscribe to events
  recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", e => {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  });

  recorder.addEventListener("start", () => {
    startDelay = performance.now() - startTime;
  });

  recorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
    const blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: "audio/webm"});

    /* if I weren't doing the trimming, I could save the recording using this */
    $("#download").setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob));

    /* fix the length */
    const ctx = new AudioContext();
    const silenceLength = Math.floor(startDelay * ctx.sampleRate / 1000);

    new Response(blob).arrayBuffer().then(arr => {
      ctx.decodeAudioData(arr, (recorded) => {
        const buffer = ctx.createBuffer(recorded.numberOfChannels, desiredLength * ctx.sampleRate / 1000, ctx.sampleRate);
        for (let i = 0; i < buffer.numberOfChannels; ++i) {
          const channel = buffer.getChannelData(i);
          const rChannel = recorded.getChannelData(i);
          buffer.copyToChannel(rChannel.slice(0, channel.length - silenceLength), i, silenceLength);
        }

        /* buffer is now padded to the correct length --- where do I go from here? */
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start recording</button>
<button id="stop">Stop recording</button>

<a download="audio.webm" id="download">Download</a>
```

**EDIT:** creating `stream` and `recorder` in advance significantly reduces `startDelay`, but some amount of correction is still needed.